# Precedencia de operadores lógicos

Tags: javascript

Me puse a reforzar conocimientos de js, y me puse a ver operadores lógicos. Noté algo raro mientras probaba unas cosas.

```js
function condicion (num) {
    if (num > 9 && num % 2 === 0 || num === 3) {
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

El problema es que si paso de parámetro 3 me devuelve `true`, pero si no se cumple la primera condición, no deberían seguir ejecutándose las siguientes condiciones ya que se usa `AND`, y si la primera condición es `false`, la siguiente no debería ejecutarse.

Comment: && tiene preferencia sobre || así que a && b || c se ejecutará como (a && b) || c

Comment: Más info en [MDN > Javascript > Precedencia de operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence)

Comment: a ver si pasas un 3 la lógica que se evalúa es `false && false || true` eso es `true` por donde se le vea en cualquier lenguaje de programación aquí no hay cortocircuito ni nada

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que en javascript: `&&` (`AND`) y `||` (`OR`) son evaluados de izquierda a derecha. Sin embargo, la evaluación no siempre sigue un estricto orden de izquierda a derecha debido a la optimización de cortocircuito. el cual no voy a entrar en detalles ya que es material de estudio solo te dejo el link: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_de_cortocircuito

Pero si te dejo la respuesta, y es implementar el uso de `( )` para anidar las comparaciones y forzar el analisis de forma correctamente logica segun lo que desees implementar:

```
function condicion(num) {
  if ((num > 9 && num % 2 === 0) || num === 3) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta, el cortocircuito no cambia el resultado de la operación solo la evaluación del operando.- Los operadores `&&` y `||` no tienen el mismo nivel de precedencia por lo tanto no sigue un `estricto orden de izquierda a derecha` como tu señalas, esto lo puedes ver con que `true || true && false` es `true`, pero `(true || true) && false` es `false`. Solo casualmente esta operación al tener el `&&` primero se ejecuta de izquierda a derecha

Comment: donde yo dije que cambia el resultado de la operación?

Comment: @Yussef antes de asegurar algo, por favor lee bien...

Comment: Tu dices que  "la evaluación no siempre sigue un estricto orden de izquierda a derecha debido a la optimización de cortocircuito", esto NO es así, el corto circuito no cambia el orden, es la precedencia el que cambia el orden. Y si bien no dices que cambia el resultado explícitamente, al decir que cambia el orden queda implícito que puede cambiar el resultado, tal como la precedencia (que cambia el orden de izq-der) lo hace.

Comment: @Yussef creo que no comprendes, que es un operador de corto circuito, si el priemer elemento es falso, no evaluara el segundo y saltara al tercero, lee la documentacion por favor por eso se emplea `()` para forzar que no ocurra ese salto, arbitrario, lo que argumentas en tu respuesta es una percepcion no es lo que realmente ocurre, y no lo digo yo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND

Comment: como lo dice la documentacion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057305/22473069

Comment: aqui hay una mejor descripcion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: repito no lo digo yo esta en la documentacion ...

Comment: Creo que no has entendido lo que ponen esos mismos enlaces. El corto circuito y la precedencia son cosas distintas, colocar paréntesis cambian el resultado según donde los pongas, porque cambia la precedencia. Por otro lado el cortocircuito nunca cambia el resultado final. Es el mismo error de concepto que tiene el OP y tu se lo estas reafirmando.

Comment: piensa lo que quieras yo estoy claro en el concepto y como se aplica en diferentes operadores y lenguajes, si la documentacion dice que _no evalua el segundo parametro_ es por que es tacito que se lo esta saltando y continua a la derecha en donde encuentra un _OR_ y ese operador provocara que retorne un _true_ ...

Comment: Claro que lo salta, pero ese no el motivo porque la expresión del OP da `true`, ya que si no lo salta da `true` de igual manera. El tema del corto circuito es relevante solo porque el OP lo menciona tácitamente, pero lo comprende mal. Tu casi reafirmas al OP que el tema pasa por ahí, cuando no es así

Comment: del problema esta claro que es el cortocircuito si no lo vez de esa forma entonces no comprenderas jamas las operaciones ternarias.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tu dices:

> pero si no se cumple la primera condicion, no deberia seguir
> ejecutandose las siguientes condicionas ya se usa AND

Esto se conoce como *evaluación de cortocircuito* y se produce en **UNA** operación `and` cuando el primer argumento es falso y en un `or` cuando el primer argumento es verdadero. Porque obviamente no hay otro resultado posible

Pero en tu caso tienes **DOS** operaciones que se deben ejecutar (ambas). Y el primer argumento de la segunda operación (el `or`) es `false`, por lo que no hay *cortocircuito* en esta operación:

Lo importante en tu pregunta es la precedencia en donde el `&&` tiene mayor precedencia que el `||`, es decir tu operación es igual a :

`( num > 9 && num % 2 === 0 ) || num === 3`

De tal manera que si `num=3`:

```
num > 9      -> false
num % 2 == 0 -> false
num == 3     -> true
```

Entonces tienes

```
(false && false || true) 
     \     /
      false     || true
        \          /
            true
```

---

Creo necesario hacer una aclaración la *evaluación de cortocircuito* **no cambia el resultado** en ningún caso, si no existiera este mecanismo el resultado sigue siendo exactamente el mismo.

El corto circuito provoca (o no) la evaluación del operando, nada mas.

Ejemplo:

```js
function A() { console.log('called A'); return false; }
function B() { console.log('called B'); return false; }
function C() { console.log('called C'); return true; }


console.log(A() && B() || C());
```

Como se puede ver la función `B()` no se evalúa porque no es necesario, y aunque se ejecutará el resultado final no cambia.

Por otro lado solo `casualmente` tu operación se ejecuta de izquierda a derecha, tal como señalé más arriba el `&&` tiene mayor nivel de precedencia que el `||`

Esto se demuestra con:

```js
console.log(true || true && false);  //true
console.log(true || (true && false));  //true
console.log((true || true) && false); //false
```